# Making php identify if right button was clicked

Tags: php, html

I am making a simple website with profiles, profile editing etc. I'm trying to make it possible so a person can change they preferences like showing age etc with profile editing. Since I want to add a button to every changeable thing possible, I need to add multiple submit buttons. There is where my problem kicks in. I've tried making it `if($submitshowage)` `(isset($submitshowage))`, but since my second button has no idea of this index, it gives me `Notice: Undefined index: submitshowage in /storage/ssd4/637/3688637/public_html/profile/editprocess.php on line 16` error.

My question is how can I make multiple buttons work and not ask about info that other buttons only give out.

my edit.php

```
<form action="editprocess.php" method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="showage" value="Yes" checked>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="showage" value="No">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submitshowage" value="submit">
</form>

<form action="editprocess.php" method="POST">
<p>Show your age publicly?</p>
<input type="radio" name="showage" value="Yes" checked> Yes
<br>
<input type="radio" name="showage" value="No"> No
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submittest" value="submit">
</form>
```

my editprocess.php

```
       <?php
//Show age proberty
$submitshowage = $_POST['submitshowage'];
if($submitshowage) {
 if ($_POST['showage'] == 'Yes'){
     $answer = 1;
 } else {
     $answer = 0;
 }
    //id from cookie
    $id = $_COOKIE['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE login SET showage='$answer' WHERE id='$id'";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

    $conn->close();
} else { }
    ?>
```

All things that could be made easier (unless necesary to buttons) Don't matter since it's my first php project and not planning on doing something with it other than have fun and see where it leads me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this code:

```
$submitshowage = $_POST['submitshowage'];
if($submitshowage) {
```

to:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitshowage']) {
```

and you can use similar code for your other submit buttons e.g.

```
if (isset($_POST['submitshowemail']) {
```

Comment: i was pretty positive that i tried it already and gave same error but now it worked like a charm